# SQL Server Multiple Index Solution?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, composite-index

Let's assume we have a table with name `Tournament` and columns of this table are `Id, Name, GameId, TypeId, cityId, Status, Format`. Except `Id` and `Name` columns I want to search this table with all of the combinations of these columns, I mean I can search with `GameId & Status` or `TypeId & CityId & Status` or `Status & Format`.

As you can see all of the search options count is equal to

```
=C(5,1)+C(5,2)+C(5,3)+C(5,4)+C(5,5).
```

So here is my question,what is the best indexing scenario and why? I think the options are,

1. Index for each column.
2. Composite ındex for all columns.

I know composite index is really faster than single index but if you go correct order, I mean if I have a composite index on `[GameId, TypeId, CityId, Status, Format]` columns and search like `GameId = 1 & TypeId = 2 & CityId = 3 & Status = 5 & Format = 6` it will work great, but how about if I search `GameId = 1 & Format = 6` I can not realize how this query will works fast enough, as I know SQL Server composite index is just a b-tree and the b-tree keys of composite index are ordered from left to right columns.

Comment: what do you intend to use as the clustered index?

Comment: If you need to search by every possible combination of values - you either need to have one index for each possible combination of columns - or you just skip indexes at all, since they most likely won't be used anyway....... seriously: scenarios like these are rarely handled well. Try to identify the **most common** queries - those top 3 queries that make up 80% of your searches - and then index **those** to speed up the most common queries - and just forget the rest

Comment: i think u are absolutely right marc_s, thanks for ur reply.